# What is the insulation material on the wire for this PCB transformer?

Tags: transformer, identification, wire, insulation, materials

Circled below:

[image]

It's a bit wrinkled. Can anyone tell just from the texture and color?

Comment: Thread or tape served litz?

Comment: Looks like celephane to me

Comment: mica tape?.... is common but not sure

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Mica Tape. This is used in HV Dry Power transformers.

> Phlogopite mica tape (magnesium silicoaluminate) on a fibreglass backing is comprised of a fine-grade phlogopite paper impregnated with a specific high temperature-resistant binder, and reinforced with fibreglass applied to one side of the mica.

https://www.final-materials.com/gb/157-mica-tape

> The dielectric withstand of the product remains constant up to 380°C. Dielectric withstand is reduced by half at 700°C, and reaches 5 kV/mm towards a temperature of 1000°C. The fibreglass backing renders the product non-combustible, such that there is no resulting thermal input during the conduct of the flame propagation test.